# JS remove elements from array of objects if element value is in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array

```
[
["BS-BLACK-2", ..., "0"]
["BS-BLACK-3", ..., "0"],
["BS-BLACK-4", ..., "0"],
["BS-BLACK-5", ..., "0"]
]
```

And another array

```
["BS-BLACK-2","BS-BLACK-3"]
```

How to exclude all elements in 1st array if values found in second array. to have:

```
[["BS-BLACK-4", ..., "0"],["BS-BLACK-5", ..., "0"]]
```

I use below code but it works only with not nested arrays

```
newArray= oldArray.filter(function (el) {
             return !toExcludeAray.includes(el);
}
```

Comment: Are the values to exclude always at index 0 in the nested arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `el[0]` if `BS-BLACK-2`, `BS-BLACK-3`.. always at `0th` index.

```js
let oldArray = [
["BS-BLACK-2", "0"],
["BS-BLACK-3", "0"],
["BS-BLACK-4", "0"],
["BS-BLACK-5", "0"]
];


let toExcludeAray = ["BS-BLACK-2","BS-BLACK-3"];

let newArray = oldArray.filter(function (el) {
   return !toExcludeAray.includes(el[0]);
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) inside a [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) call on your input data to exclude the elements based on the second array. `[firstValue]` corresponds to [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the first value in the nested array element.

```js
const input = [
    ["BS-BLACK-2", "0"],
    ["BS-BLACK-3", "0"],
    ["BS-BLACK-4", "0"],
    ["BS-BLACK-5", "0"]
];
const toExclude = ["BS-BLACK-2","BS-BLACK-3"];
const filtered = input.filter(([firstValue]) => (!toExclude.includes(firstValue)));
console.log(filtered);
```